# How to set background color in macOS in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am very new to macOS implementation. Can you guys please suggest any documentations that show how to get some grip on menus, background colors, text fields, and all UIElements programmatically  without using Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here! http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html
Check the setBackground:(NSColor *)color method

Mucking around with colours is lots of fun, but read the Apple Human Interface Guidelines before publishing an app with coloured textfields...

Answer (score 0):

Use Apple's developer documentation. If you are looking for information on how to use a specific class, you can load it's reference page and check the companion guide/sample code sections. http://developer.apple.com/mac/

Answer (score -2):

Make a label background red:

```
self.textField.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
```

To Clear it:

```
self.textField.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
```